# How to voxelize a large .obj scene?

Tags: 3d, modeling, magicavoxel

I need to voxelize a large scene ( over 500 x 500 x 500 ).

Of course I tried MagicaVoxel but it has a limitation ( 126 x 126 x 126 ).

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

you could try the vengi-voxconvert, it probably will take a very long time to convert though because voxelizing is not a cheap process. i have a tutorial here https://youtu.be/Erstqc5uSxU just make sure u decimate and reduce the number of faces and make sure your model is not too big "meter"-wise try scaling it down meter-wise if possible before conversion attempt. try with a small 1m x 1m x 1m object first to test it out to get a feel of the software.